# How to parallelize for loops using multithreading in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I am not familiar with python. I want to parallelize the outer for loop for the following pseudo-code:

```
for(i=1 to N){  // N and n will be taken as input for the shell script. 
   min=some garbage value
   for(j=1 to n){
       val= './a.out' // call the executable a.out and take the output in val
       if(val<min)    // a.out is a random number generator script
           min=val; 
   }
   arr[k++]=min;
}
// Then I want to calculate the sum of the elements of the array 'arr'.
```

I tried to use shell script as follows. But N can be very large. So, I need to use 
multi-threading to parallelize the outer for loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set min to some garbage value

N=$1
n=$2
for (( i=1; i<=$N; i++ )); do
   min=100000000
   for (( j=1; j<=$n; j++ )); do
       val=$(/path/to/a.out)
       val2=`echo $val | bc`    // is this the correct syntax?
       if (( $val2 < $min )); then
           min=$val2; 
       fi   
   done
   arr=("${arr[@]}" "$min")
done

# Then I want to calculate the sum of the elements of the array 'arr'.
sum=0
for (( l=0; l<${#arr[@]}; l++ )); do
  sum=$( expr $sum + ${arr[$l]} )
done

echo "Sum of \$arr = ${sum}"
```

Comment: is your number generator program takes considerable amount of CPU time? If not, you would hardly gain any benefit in running the inner loop in multiple threads. Few synchronization would be required once to calculate the min value and once to update the arr.

Comment: Do you need to use a compiled random number generator? Python has got a `random` module. Python also can add up all the elements in an array with the built-in `sum` function (e.g. `sum([1,2,3])` will give an answer of 6).

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to the question for future reference, even though I share the concerns raised by other posters on whether parallelizing is the right road to follow on this specific example.

To parallelize a simple for loop with threading, you can of course use the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). In addition, [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) brings a simpler syntax on top of them (be careful to switch it to the threading backend).

Disclaimer: I am the original author of joblib.